# Listing with line numbers inside a table

Tags: tables, listings, line-numbering

I typeset a lot of listings (using the `listings` package) inside (`array`-based) `tabular` environments. This works like a charm, however, breaks when I pass the `numbers=` option to the listing:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{8cm}}
  % The following works if you remove the numbers=left option
  \begin{lstlisting}[language=C,basicstyle=\ttfamily, numbers=left, gobble=4]
    int main(){
      printf("Hello, Bug\n");
    }
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

This fails with the error message:

```
Runaway definition?
#1\\left\unskip \relax \@endpbox \hskip \col@sep 
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning definition of \lst@temp.
<inserted text> 
            }
l.9 ...sicstyle=\ttfamily, numbers=left, gobble=4]
```

Any idea, what causes this problem?

Is there a possible workaround (besides external boxing or falling back to `\lstinputlisting`)?

Comment: I don't know if this has side effects, but putting the environment inside braces doesn't trigger the error.

Comment: @egreg: That indeed seems to solve the problem. Did you somehow figure this by looking at the source or was it just "trial-and-error"?

Comment: Why are you putting a `lstlisting` in a `tabular` float?

Comment: Side note: If you have many same styled listings, then create proper environment for them, e.g. `\lstnewenvironment{c-numbers}{\lstset{language=C,basicstyle=\ttfamily,numbers=left,gobble=4}}{}` (so you can later just type `\begin{c-numbers}...\end{c-numbers}`). If all of your listings have same settings, then just use once `\lstset{...}` in preamble of your document.

Comment: @przemoc: Right, I am using this all the time. However, both do not actually contribute to a MWE.

Comment: @You: A `tabular` is not a float, so I do not completely understand your comment. However, I use `tabular` to achieve some complicated layout - which I intentionally have left out from the MWE, as it does not contribute to the illustration of the problem.

Comment: @Daniel: Oops, my bad.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem seems to be solvable by putting the `lstlisting` environment in braces:

```
\begin{tabular}{p{8cm}}
  {\begin{lstlisting}[language=C,basicstyle=\ttfamily, numbers=left, gobble=4]
    int main(){
      printf("Hello, Bug\n");
    }
  \end{lstlisting}}
\end{tabular}
```

It seems that without braces the macros of **listings** go "too far" and try to look at the internal token that finishes table cells (the TeXbook calls it `\endtemplate`, but it cannot really be written in any way in a document). The clue was indeed the "Forbidden control sequence found" message.