# error using tcblisting inside tabular when numbers is set

Tags: listings, tcolorbox

`tcblisting` gives error when adding `numbers=left`, but it does this only when inside tabular or longtable.

This compiles OK

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{bg}{RGB}{240,240,240}    
\usepackage{upquote} %to fix string quotes
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{many,listings}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.5\textwidth} |}
\begin{tcblisting}{
     nobeforeafter,
     listing only,
     size=minimal,
     listing options={language=Mathematica,
                    framerule=0.05pt,
                    %numbers=left,
                    numberstyle=\scriptsize,
                    basicstyle=\ttfamily\normalsize,
                    breaklines         = true,
                    showspaces         = false}
    }
x=10;
\end{tcblisting}
\end{tabular}    
\end{document}
```

Now, setting `numbers=left` above (un comment), it gives this error

```
lualatex foo3.tex
This is LuaTeX, Version 0.95.0 (TeX Live 2016) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./foo3.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 1
...
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstlang1.sty)
Runaway definition?
#1\\left\@endpbox \hskip \tabcolsep \hskip -.5\arrayrulewidth \vrule \ETC.
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning definition of \lst@temp.
<inserted text> 
}
l.26 \end{tcblisting}

?
```

Moving `tcblisting` outside the table, it compiles ok, with `numbers=left` in place.
So the error only shows up when inside table environment. Same error when using `lstlisting` , but there is a workaround for `lstlisting` given in  [listing-with-line-numbers-inside-a-table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21663/listing-with-line-numbers-inside-a-table)  which is to put `{}` around the whole environment. It works for `{\begin{lstlisting}...\end{lstlisting}}` and the error goes away, but this solution does not work for `\begin{tcblisting}`, here is my try, which is to add `{ }` around the whole thing, same as in the above fix, but it did not work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{bg}{RGB}{240,240,240}    
\usepackage{upquote} %to fix string quotes
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{many,listings}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.5\textwidth} |}
{\begin{tcblisting}{
     nobeforeafter,
     listing only,
     size=minimal,
     listing options={language=Mathematica,
                    framerule=0.05pt,
                    numbers=left,
                    numberstyle=\scriptsize,
                    basicstyle=\ttfamily\normalsize,
                    breaklines         = true,
                    showspaces         = false}
    }
x=10;
\end{tcblisting}}
\end{tabular}    
\end{document}
```

Error is

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstlang1.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstlang1.sty)
(./foo3.listing)

LaTeX Warning: Characters dropped after `\end{tcblisting}' on input line 25.

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.26     \end{tabular}

?
```

Question is: Can `numbers=left` be made to work with `tcblisting` inside table as well?

Tl 2016 on Linux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `tcblisting` is a verbatim environment it has to see the correct `\end{tcblisting}`,so use `\scantokens{\begin{tcblisting}...\end{tcblisting}`.

The number can be shifted into the tabular with some `left skip` value.

[image]

This compiles for me both with LuaLaTeX and pdfLaTeX  (on TL 2015, not updated on my old notebook yet)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{bg}{RGB}{240,240,240}    
\usepackage{upquote} %to fix string quotes
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{many,listings}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.5\textwidth}|}
{\scantokens{\begin{tcblisting}{%
        nobeforeafter,
        left skip=20pt,
        listing only,
        size=minimal,
        listing options={language=Mathematica,
          framerule=0.05pt,
          numbers=left,
          numberstyle=\scriptsize,
          basicstyle=\ttfamily\normalsize,
          breaklines         = true,
          showspaces         = false}
      }
      x=10;
\end{tcblisting}}}
\end{tabular}    
\end{document}
```